# Rails Admin - Perform a search into an has_many associated model not loading table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am implementing Rails Admin for a client and I have two models `Job` and `Candidacy`. A `Job` has many `candidacies`.From Rails Admin Job Panel, I would like to do a date filter to search between two dates if there is any candidacies.

Here is the code :

```rb
# app/models/job.rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :candidacies

end
```

```rb
# app/models/candidacy.rb
class Candidacy < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :job

end
```

```rb
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

RailsAdmin.config do |config|

 config.model 'Job' do
  list do
   field :candidacies, :date do
    searchable [{Candidacy => :created_at}]
   end
  end
 end
end
```

When I click on Candidacies Filter and filter between two dates.
It raises an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RailsAdmin::Main#index
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "candidacies"
```

I have all the detail about the SQL query and it is not loading the `candidacies` table.

```sql
SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE candidacies.created_at BETWEEN '2019-12-11 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-14 23:59:59'
```

Any idea how to config rails admin to load the table `candidacies` ?

Thanks !!!

***1st Edit :***

It works when a add a `default_scope` to my model `Job`.
But I don't know if it is the proper way to do it.

```rb
# app/models/job.rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :candidacies
 default_scope { eager_load(:candidacies) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid eager loading the other table in all future Job queries i suggest you keep the scope only on the job list config.

```
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
 config.model 'Job' do
  list do
   field :candidacies, :date do
    searchable [{Candidacy => :created_at}]
   end

   scopes [:with_candidacies]
  end
 end
end
```

And the model

```
# app/models/job.rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :candidacies
 scope :with_candidacies, -> { eager_load(:candidacies) }
end
```

Rails admin will auto apply the first scope.

Comment: I have followed your code in the model & the config. And it raises :
```undefined method `scopes' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::HasManyAssociation:0x00007fd8c63a6d20>``` when I try to load `admin/jobs`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i indented it inside the field and scopes should be inside the lists block